# Retreive all individual strings in a string separated by a period php

Tags: php

Suppose I have a string

```
$str = "exampleemail1@gmail.com $exampleemail@gmail.com exampleemail3@gmail.com";
```

How can I retreive the individual strings that are being separated by the space only?ie $str[0]="exampleemail1@gmail.com" etc

I know how to retreive individual words using

```
$words = str_word_count($str,1);//Returns an array of the words in the string
```

How would I go about doing the same for a string with special characters?

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote PHP explode().  Based on the examples and the expected output, it would work correctly.  You can test this stuff with nothing more than a few lines of code.  The presence of special characters (ie: the dollar sign) is not an issue for explode().

Comment: It worked perfectly @RayPaseur.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `explode`

```
$str = "test@test.com test2@test.com test3@test.com";
$exploded = explode(" ",$str); //returns array of strings.
echo $exploded[0]; //output test@test.com
echo $exploded[1]; //output test2@test.com
```